# Select function behavior - Multi Client Quiz

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming, application-layer

I have to build a quiz application.

**Details about the application:**
1. Each client has to register to server before participating in Quiz. The server will ask
username from each user and generate temporary id for each user.
2. After Registration process clients, who are successfully connected to server will get
Question from server.
3. The client will reply with answer.
4. Server will receive answer from different clients with time stamps, and it will calculate
time difference of each client which is called ∆t.

```
    Define such as:  
    ∆t = (Time Question sent - Time answer received) - RTT  
    Where RTT is Round Trip Time
```

1. Server will select client, whose ∆t is minimum to all and reply with whatever score client will gain remains will not gain any score.
2. After sending Question server will wait Answer for a particular time periods called (T). If client did not reply within ‘T’ time period Server will skip that Question and goes to next Question.

**Pseudocode of main loop in my server code**

```
A. A main while loop which runs once for each question.  
B. Inside this first I am accepting login for 10 seconds.  
       Here I am assigning user Id and all other initialization stuff.  
C. Then using `select` to check which are available for writing.
       To available connections I am checking `RTT` and then sending question to each user.
D. Then I am waiting for some time to get answers.
       Here I am using `select` to determine where the answer is available to read.
E. Then I am repeating steps C. and D.
```

**Problem**:
When I connect only to a single client my code works fine for any number of question.
But when I test this code on multiple client with the same client code:

- Login for everyone is OK.
- Sending First Question to everyone works fine.
- **Then while waiting for the answer I only received answer from one client. Each client shows that answer is been sent. For second client the second `select` function doesn't return with readable data availability.**

*Why for multi-client my code is not working. (According to me the error is somewhere in getting answer).*

***My Code***:
*The structure of the packets send can be understand easily from the variable names.*

**Server.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

#define PORT "3490" //the port user will be connecting to
#define BACKLOG 10  //how many pending connection queue will hold
#define maxUser 10
#define LOGIN_OK "OK"
#define LOGIN_WrongPassword "NP"
#define LOGIN_WrongUsername "NU"
#define MAX_USERS 10
#define MAX_ANSWER_TIME 10
#define LOGIN_WAIT 10
#define TOTAL_QUES "3"

int users[MAX_USERS][3] = {};  //index is userID, 0 is no user

void sigchld_handler(int s)
{
    while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
}

//get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6

int timer;
void alarm_handler(int s) {
    timer = 0;
}

wrongRecv(ssize_t recvd, ssize_t expctd)
{

    if(recvd != expctd)
    {
        printf("Recvd(%zd) bytes not equal to expected(%zd) bytes\n",recvd,expctd);
        //getchar();
    }
}

//void nextQues(char* quesMsg, char* ques, char* optA, char* optB, char* optC, char* optD)
int nextQues(char* quesMsg, int QID)
{
    char ques[40], optA[10], optB[10], optC[10], optD[10], quesId[5];

    sprintf(quesId,"%d",QID);
    strncpy(ques, "This is the question?",22);
    strncpy(optA, "OptionA", 7);    strncpy(optB, "OptionB", 7);    strncpy(optC, "OptionC", 7);    strncpy(optD, "OptionD", 7);
    strncpy(quesMsg,quesId,5);
    strncpy(quesMsg + 05,ques,40);
    strncpy(quesMsg + 45,optA,10);
    strncpy(quesMsg + 55,optB,10);
    strncpy(quesMsg + 65,optC,10);
    strncpy(quesMsg + 75,optD,10);

    return 0;
}

//void answerCheck(char* ques, char* optA, char* optB, char* optC, char* optD, char* usrResponse, int rtt, int timeTaken)
void answerCheck(int fd, char usrResponse[6], int rtt, int timeTaken)
{
    int responseTime, i;
    char actualAnswer[1];
    char quesId[5];
    printf("fd(%d) quesid(%s) response(%c) rtt(%d) timeTaken(%d)\n", fd, usrResponse, usrResponse[5], rtt, timeTaken );
    strncpy(quesId, usrResponse, 5);
    actualAnswer[0] = 'B';//we have quesId we can find actual answer on basis of it

    if(actualAnswer[0] == usrResponse[5])
    {
        //printf("%s\n","+++++" );
        responseTime = timeTaken - rtt;
        //printf("Response Time(%d)\n",responseTime);

        //save it with user id

        //finding userid
        for(i = 0; i < MAX_USERS; i++) {
            if(users[i][1] == fd) {
                users[i][2] = responseTime;//saving it
                //printf("%d\n",i );
            }
        }
    }
}

int compareAnswer() {
    int i, min = 2 * MAX_ANSWER_TIME, userIndex;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_USERS; i++) {
        if(users[i][2] < min) {
            min = users[i][2];
            userIndex = i;
        }
    }
    //Increasing Score
    users[userIndex][0]++;

    //returning fd
    return users[userIndex][1];
}

void users_deleteFd(int fd) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_USERS; ++i)
    {
        if(users[i][1] == fd) {
            users[i][1] =0;
            return;
        }
    }
}

int rtt_check(int new_fd)
{
    ssize_t send_ret, recv_ret;
    char rtt_check[1];
    time_t rtt1, rtt2;

    rtt1 = time(NULL);
    send_ret = send(new_fd, "r", 1, 0);
    if(send_ret == 0)
    {
        return -2;
    }
    wrongRecv(send_ret, 1);
    //printf("%s\n","Between two phase of rttCheck" );
    recv_ret = recv(new_fd, rtt_check, 1,0);
    rtt2 = time(NULL);
    if(recv_ret == 0)
    {
        return -2;
    }
    wrongRecv(recv_ret,1);
    //printf("diff(%d)\n",(int) difftime(rtt2,rtt1));

    return  (int) difftime(rtt2,rtt1);
}

int login(char user[], char pass[])
{
    //for user
    static int Id = 0; //when have function getUserID, make it not static and also remove Id++;
    if(!strcmp(user,"abhishek") && !strcmp(pass,"abhishek")) {
        //Id = getUserID(user);
        return ++Id;
    }else if(!strcmp(user,"abhishek")){
        return 0; //wrong password
    }
    return -1; //wrong username
}

int totalQues;

int login_setup(int new_fd)
{
    //login inititalizations
    char login_det[16];
    char username[9],password[9], login_statMsg[7], totalQuesMsg[5] = TOTAL_QUES;
    totalQues = atoi(totalQuesMsg);
    //for user
    int userId;

    //for wrongRecv
    ssize_t send_ret,recv_ret;

    //getting username and password
    recv_ret = recv(new_fd,login_det,16,0);
    if(recv_ret == 0)
    {
        return -2;
    }
    wrongRecv(recv_ret,16);

    //extracting username nad password
    strncpy(username,login_det,8);  
    strncpy(password,login_det+8,8);
    username[8]='\0'; password[8]='\0';
    //printf("username(%s) and password(%s)\n",username,password);

    if( (userId = login(username,password)) > 0) {
        //printf("%d\n",userId);

        //sending status
        strncpy(login_statMsg, LOGIN_OK, 2);
        strncpy(login_statMsg + 2, totalQuesMsg , 5);
        send_ret = send(new_fd, login_statMsg,7,0);
        if(send_ret == 0)
        {
            return -2;
        }
        wrongRecv(send_ret,7);

        //TODO error checking then handling if error

        //users[userId][0] = 0; //score
        users[userId][1] = new_fd; //file descriptor associated with this user
        //users[userId][2] = 0; //answer time
        return 1;
    }
    else if(userId == -1) { //wrong username
        strncpy(login_statMsg, LOGIN_WrongUsername, 2);
        strncpy(login_statMsg + 2, totalQuesMsg , 5);
        send_ret = send(new_fd, login_statMsg,7,0);
        if(send_ret == 0)
        {
            return -2;
        }
        wrongRecv(send_ret,7);
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        strncpy(login_statMsg, LOGIN_WrongPassword, 2);
        strncpy(login_statMsg + 2, totalQuesMsg , 5);
        send_ret = send(new_fd, login_statMsg,7,0);
        if(send_ret == 0)
        {
            return -2;
        }
        wrongRecv(send_ret,7);      
        return 0;
    }
    //TODO erorr handling of above two case
    //TODO make login a loop
}


void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}


int main(void)
{
    int listen_fd, new_fd; // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;//connection's address info
    socklen_t sin_size;
    int yes=1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;//IPv4 or IPv6
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    if((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL,PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0){ //getting which IPv server supports
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n",gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    //loop through all the result and bind to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p  = p->ai_next){
        if((listen_fd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1){
            perror("server : socket");
            continue;
        }

        if(setsockopt(listen_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1){
            perror("set sockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(bind(listen_fd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1){
            close(listen_fd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if(p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "server:failed to bind\n");
        return 2;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);//all done with this structure

    if(listen(listen_fd, BACKLOG) == -1){
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }
    //printf("listen_fd(%d)\n",listen_fd );

//  sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
//  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
//  sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
//  if(sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1){
//      perror("sigaction");
//      exit(1);
//  }

    printf("server waiting for connections.....\n");

    fd_set master; //master file descriptor list
    fd_set read_fds; //temp file descriptor list for select()
    int fdmax;
    FD_ZERO(&master); //clear the master and temp sets
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);

    FD_SET(listen_fd, &master);

    //keep track of the bigge file descriptor
    fdmax = listen_fd; // so far it is this one

    ssize_t recv_ret, send_ret;


    //for login
    int loginStatus;
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = alarm_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    //sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if(sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL) == -1){
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }


    //login while
    alarm(LOGIN_WAIT);//accepting login only for 10 seconds
    timer = 1;
    printf("\n-----------------------------Waiting for users to login for %d seconds.-----------------------------\n",LOGIN_WAIT);
    while(timer) {
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
        if(new_fd == -1){
            //perror("accept");
            break;// this break is very important , as we are using alarm(Signals) and accept is a blocking function
                    //If accept is in blocked sate and our signal comes then accept will exit returning error. So
                    //if error then we have to break else next satements will run on falsy values.
                    //In reality we dont need this as I alredy set the SA_RESTART flag in sigaction which means
                    //after returning from the signal handler restart the activity on which you are previously
                    //instead of starting execution from next line.
        }else {

            inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr), s, sizeof s);
            printf("server : got connection from %s\n", s);

            //LOGIN     //need to call login function via thread because this 
                            //may stop the function if user doesnot respond
            loginStatus = login_setup(new_fd);

            //adding to select checkup
            if(loginStatus) {
                printf("User Loginned Succesfully\n");
            }
        }
    }
    printf("-----------------------------Login Closed. Now starting the QUIZ.-----------------------------\n");

    //for randome seek
    srand(time(NULL));

    //for main loop counter
    int i, win_fd;

    //for questions
    int QID = 0;
    int maxQues_Len = 40, maxOpt_len = 10, maxQuesId_len = 5;//including '\0' this time
    char quesMsg[80], answer[6];//score doesnot include \0
    //char ques[40], optA[10], optB[10], optC[10], optD[10];

    //for time calculation of each answer
    ssize_t time_ques, time_ans;

    //getting all avialable participants
    fdmax = 0;
    FD_ZERO(&master);
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_USERS; i++) {
        if( (new_fd = users[i][1]) != 0){
            FD_SET(new_fd, &master);
            if(new_fd > fdmax)
                fdmax = new_fd;
            //printf("%d\n",new_fd);
        }
    }

    int current_rtt;
    //while for main quiz
    while(totalQues--) {

        //checking who are ready for witing
        if(select(fdmax+1, NULL, &master, NULL, NULL) == -1){//here select will return withh all the descriptors which are 
                                                                //ready to write , all others have to miss this question
            perror("select");
            exit(1);
        }

        //setting which question to send
        QID++;

        //for sending questions to all
        for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++) {
            if(FD_ISSET(i, &master)) {
                //rtt check
                current_rtt = rtt_check(i);
                if(current_rtt == -2) {//connection closed
                    FD_CLR(i, &master);
                    users_deleteFd(i);
                    continue;
                }
                //setting question
                //nextQues(quesMsg, ques, optA, optB, optC, optD);
                nextQues(quesMsg, QID);
                printf("Sending Question QID(%s) fd(%d)\n",quesMsg,i);
                //send a question
                time_ques = time(NULL);
                send_ret = send(i, quesMsg, maxQues_Len + 4 * maxOpt_len + maxQuesId_len, 0);
                if(send_ret == 0) {//connection closed
                    FD_CLR(i, &master);
                    users_deleteFd(i);
                    continue;
                }
                wrongRecv(send_ret, maxQues_Len + 4 * maxOpt_len + maxQuesId_len);  
            }
        }

        //ASSUMING Question is send ot all the users at same time       
        //receiving and waiting for answers
        alarm(MAX_ANSWER_TIME);
        timer = 1;
        FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
        read_fds = master;
        // unsigned int qq = read_fds.fd_count;
        // for (int ii = 0; ii < qq; ++ii)
        // {
        //  printf("%d\n",read_fds.fd_array[i] );
        // }
        while(timer) {
            //printf("HURRAY\n");
            if(select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) <=0){
                perror("select");
                //exit(4);
                break;//break is important. Explained above
            }

            for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++) {
                //printf("Recving answer I(%d)\n",i);
                if(FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)) {
                    //receiving answer
                    //TODO if we get answer to wrong ques
                    printf("Recving answer I(%d) fdmax (%d)\n",i,fdmax);
                    recv_ret = recv(i,answer,6,0);
                    time_ans = time(NULL);
                    wrongRecv(recv_ret,6);
                    printf("%s\n",answer );
                    if(recv_ret == 0)//connection closed
                    {
                        FD_CLR(i, &read_fds);
                        FD_CLR(i, &master);
                        users_deleteFd(i);
                        continue;
                    }else if(recv_ret > 0){
                        if(QID == atoi(answer)) { //we have received the answer to this question so remove the user from wait answer loop
                            FD_CLR(i, &read_fds);
                            //printf("%s i(%d)\n","#######",i );
                            answerCheck(i ,answer, current_rtt, (int) difftime(time_ans,time_ques));
                            //printf("Answer(%c)\n",answer[0]);
                        }
                        else{//we have recvd something unexpectable so ignore for NOW

                        }
                    }

                    //time_t cccc = time(NULL);
                    //printf("%s I(%d)\n",ctime(&cccc),i);
                }
            }
        }
        //comparing answers
        win_fd = compareAnswer();
        //sending score
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Client.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT "3490" //the port client will be connecting to

#define MAXDATASIZE 100 // max number of bytes we can get at once

//get sockaddr ,IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if(sa->sa_family ==AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

wrongRecv(ssize_t recvd, ssize_t expctd)
{

    if(recvd != expctd)
    {
        printf("Recvd(%zd) bytes not equal to expected(%zd) bytes\n",recvd,expctd);
        getchar();
    }
}

void rtt_check(int sockfd)
{
    ssize_t send_ret, recv_ret;
    char rtt_check[1];
    recv_ret = recv(sockfd, rtt_check, 1,0);
    wrongRecv(recv_ret,1);
    sleep(1);//to check
    send_ret = send(sockfd, "r", 1, 0);
    wrongRecv(send_ret, 1);

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, numbytes;
    char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if(argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: client hostname\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if((rv = getaddrinfo(argv[1], PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"getaddrinfo: %s\n",gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    //lopp through all the results and connect to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1){
            perror("client: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if(connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1){
            close(sockfd);
            perror("client: connect");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if(p ==NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"client: failed to connect\n");
        return 2;
    }

    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr), s, sizeof s);
    printf("client : connecting to %s\n", s);

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure
    char login_det[17] = "abhishekabhishek";
    char login_retMsg[7], login_stat[3], totalQuesMsg[5];
    int totalQues;

    //sending login details
    ssize_t send_ret,recv_ret;
    send_ret = send(sockfd, login_det,16,0);
    wrongRecv(send_ret,16);

    //receiving login status
    recv_ret = recv(sockfd,login_retMsg,7,0);
    wrongRecv(recv_ret,7);

    strncpy(login_stat, login_retMsg, 2);
    login_stat[2] = '\0';
    printf("Login Status(%s)\n",login_stat);
    strncpy(totalQuesMsg, login_retMsg + 2, 5);
    totalQues = atoi(totalQuesMsg);
    printf("totalQues(%d)\n",totalQues);

    if(!strcmp(login_stat,"OK")) {  //login ok
        char quesId[5];
        int maxQues_Len = 40, maxOpt_len = 10, maxQuesId_len = 5;//including '\0' this time
        char quesMsg[80], scoreMsg[1];//score doesnot include \0
        char ques[40], optA[10], optB[10], optC[10], optD[10];
        char answer[6];

        while(totalQues--) {
            //checking rtt
            rtt_check(sockfd);
            //receving question
            recv_ret = recv(sockfd, quesMsg,  maxQues_Len + 4 * maxOpt_len + maxQuesId_len ,0);
            wrongRecv(recv_ret,  maxQues_Len + 4 * maxOpt_len + maxQuesId_len);
            strncpy(quesId,quesMsg,5);
            strncpy(ques, quesMsg + 05, 40);
            strncpy(optA, quesMsg + 45, 10);
            strncpy(optB, quesMsg + 55, 10);
            strncpy(optC, quesMsg + 65, 10);
            strncpy(optD, quesMsg + 75, 10);
            printf("QUESID(%s) Question(%s), A(%s) , B(%s) , C(%s) , D(%s)\n", quesId, ques, optA, optB, optC, optD);

            //choose answer
            scoreMsg[0] = 'B';

            strncpy(answer,quesId, 5);
            answer[5] = scoreMsg[0];
            sleep(5);

            //sending answer
            send_ret = send(sockfd, answer,6,0);
            wrongRecv(send_ret,6);
            printf("%s\n","Answer Message Sent" );


            // if((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
            //  perror("recv");
            //  exit(1);
            // }

            // buf[numbytes] = '\0';

            // printf("client: received '%s'\n",buf);
        }
    } 
    //TODO wrong login
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the call to `select` in the answer getting loop is modifying `read_fds` to hold just the file descriptor of the first client(s) to respond. Since you don't reset `read_fds` before calling `select` again, it will not recognize the other clients' response.

Comment: No, I am calling the select again and agian. (after each for loop select is called again till the times up). Also if you run the code after receiving the first answer my program is blocked at the select till the times up, this means i am calling the select again.

Comment: @knoxxs, I know you are calling select again. The problem is the value of read_fds when it is called for the second time. I prefer not to give away the exact change needed since this is a homework assignment.

Comment: I am not getting it. is there any way to traverse read_fds, I have searched but don't get it. For the H.W. assignment concern. Assignment submission time is over I am asking for myself.
But as you pointed I tried and I think after receiving the first answer I am only deleting that file descriptor for `read_fds` . And as I copied it from `master`, it still contain the file descriptors of other connections.

Comment: @knoxxs, fd_set is an opaque data structure that should only be accessed with the FD_* macros. You can loop over the client connections and use FD_ISSET on each one to see what is in read_fds. Try printing this out just before the call to select. If you don't believe read_fds will be modified by the select call, read the [manpage for select(2)](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) carefully.

Comment: I believe that and I am saying for other connection it must be modified as they already sent the answer. But it is not. Why?
Sry, but I am not getting what you want to convey from your answer. Can you pls tell me directly.  
I think you could believe that I know about modification of fd_set and it macros as this code is written by me.

Comment: He's saying that you initially set up `read_fds` to represent something like `{1,2,3}`, then `select` changes it to represent `{2}`.  Then when you call `select` again using the same `read_fds` variable, you're telling `select` to only check client `2`.

Comment: @aschepler, Thanks, error is solved. But I have one more doubt that as you said after select fd_set only represents {2}.  And after reading the answer from it I am also removing this from fd_set. That means now there is nothing left in fd_set. Then why select is still blocking?

Comment: Actually I have tested select and it is blocking on a empty fd_set. Is there any reason for this ignorance of select (as select is waiting for data at no file descriptor, that is absurd) or it just a mistake.

Comment: @knoxxs: Makes sense to me. If you ask `select` to wait until an event happens on an fd which is a member of the empty set, it will wait forever.

Comment: But if I pass NULL instead of empty set it still waits. any reasons?

Comment: @knoxxs, frome the man page: "Some code calls select() with all three sets empty, nfds zero, and a non-NULL timeout as a fairly portable way to sleep with subsecond precision." NULL is the same as an empty set.